# Getting Loggedin username for Windows 7 remotely

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2, user

I have few PC at remote locations. I would like to know the user who is currently logged in to those machines. Is there a way I can get this information remotely?

I have access to AD, SCCM.

Comment: Are they added to your domain? Can you use Direct Access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PsLoggedOn is a tool included in the PSTools suite.  It pretty easy to tell what it does.

the usage is:
psloggedon \computername

It does require admin rights, but I love sharing the ps tools suite any time I can.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx
*Edit-Added Link

-Spencer